# Error trying to connect a Python client to AWS IoT becuase of the certificates

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mqtt

Hi I am pretty new in this AWS world, what I am trying to do is connect a python client to the AWS IoT service and publish a message, I am using the SDK python and its example, but I have problems whit the certification process, I already have created the thing, the policies and the certification and I downloaded the files, but in the python program I have no idea if I am writing  the path to this files in a correct way,

First I tried writing the whole path of each file and nothing then I tried just putting "certificados\thefile" and nothing .
The error that pops up says the error is the path which precesily I do not how to write it.
Thanks for taking the time and sotty if this question is too basic I am just jumping into this.

```py
# Copyright Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0

import time as t
import json
import AWSIoTPythonSDK.MQTTLib as AWSIoTPyMQTT

# Define ENDPOINT, CLIENT_ID, PATH_TO_CERT, PATH_TO_KEY, PATH_TO_ROOT, MESSAGE, TOPIC, and RANGE
ENDPOINT = "MYENDPOINT"
CLIENT_ID = "testDevice"
PATH_TO_CERT = "certificados/5a7e19a0269abe740ac8b38a1bfdab115d14074eb212167a3ba359c0d237a8c3-certificate.pem.crt"
PATH_TO_KEY = "certificados/5a7e19a0269abe740ac8b38a1bfdab115d14074eb212167a3ba359c0d237a8c3-private.pem.key"
PATH_TO_ROOT = "certificados/AmazonRootCA1.pem"
MESSAGE = "Hello World"
TOPIC = "Prueba/A"
RANGE = 20

myAWSIoTMQTTClient = AWSIoTPyMQTT.AWSIoTMQTTClient(CLIENT_ID)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureEndpoint(ENDPOINT, 8883)
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.configureCredentials(PATH_TO_ROOT, PATH_TO_KEY, PATH_TO_CERT)

myAWSIoTMQTTClient.connect()
print('Begin Publish')
for i in range (RANGE):
    data = "{} [{}]".format(MESSAGE, i+1)
    message = {"message" : data}
    myAWSIoTMQTTClient.publish(TOPIC, json.dumps(message), 1) 
    print("Published: '" + json.dumps(message) + "' to the topic: " + "'test/testing'")
    t.sleep(0.1)
print('Publish End')
myAWSIoTMQTTClient.disconnect()
```

I have created a directory on my deskopt to store this files, its name is "certificados" and from there I am taking the path but it doesn't work.

```
OSError: certificados/AmazonRootCA1.pem: No such file or directory
```

Also I am using VS code to run this application.

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages, they are hard to read and impossible for users that use screen readers.. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68747037/edit) the question to post the actual text and use the tools to format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, it can't find the CA cert file at the path you've given it. The path you've given will be interpreted relative to where the files are executed, which is most likely going to be relative to the python file it's self. If that's not the Desktop then you need to provide the fully qualified path:

So assuming Linux, change the paths to:

```
PATH_TO_CERT = "/home/user/Desktop/certificados/5a7e19a0269abe740ac8b38a1bfdab115d14074eb212167a3ba359c0d237a8c3-certificate.pem.crt"
PATH_TO_KEY = "/home/user/Desktop/certificados/5a7e19a0269abe740ac8b38a1bfdab115d14074eb212167a3ba359c0d237a8c3-private.pem.key"
PATH_TO_ROOT = "/home/user/Desktop/certificados/AmazonRootCA1.pem"
```

Comment: Thanks hardillb now it works,  the problem was that I was including the "C:"  character from the local disc in the path, also  I was using the slash in the wrong way, which is strange becuase I am on windows but it worked, thank you again.